# Spring работа со сторонним API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Изучаю Spring и вот хочу реализовать работу с методами внешнего API.

Есть готовое внешнее API, например: http://www.omdbapi.com/
Есть 2 метода поиска, каждый с одним обязательным параметром, формата:
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Blade&y=1998&plot=full

Как через Spring обработать данный запрос? То есть: подставить нужные параметры(имя, год и т.д.) и сохранить полученный JSON или обработать его?

Как в целом проводится работа со сторонним готовым API?

Буду благодарен за конкретные примеры и наводки на необходимую информацию.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону спрингового `RestTemplate`